# Start System.Diagnostics.Process with credential

Tags: powershell, system.diagnostics

We have script that successfully ran.
It`s execute encoded command and show output.

```
$EncodedCommand = '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'

$Arguments =   '-Noexit', '-NoLogo', '–NoProfile', '-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned', "-EncodedCommand $EncodedCommand"

$ProcessStartInfoParam = [ordered]@{
    Arguments       = $Arguments -join ' '
    CreateNoWindow  = $False
    FileName        = 'powershell'
    WindowStyle     = 'Normal'
    LoadUserProfile = $False
    UseShellExecute = $False
}

$ProcessStartInfo = New-Object -TypeName 'System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo' -Property $ProcessStartInfoParam
$Process = New-Object 'System.Diagnostics.Process'

$Process.StartInfo = $ProcessStartInfo
$Process.Start()
```

For better understanding i`m added scriptblock with decoded command.

```
$Error.clear()
[Console]::OutputEncoding = [System.Text.Encoding]::GetEncoding( "utf-8" )

[string] $EncodedArguments = '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'
$Arguments  = [System.Management.Automation.PSSerializer]::Deserialize( [System.Text.Encoding]::Unicode.GetString([System.Convert]::FromBase64String( $EncodedArguments )) )

$ScriptBlock = {
    #sb1
        param( $Param1, $Param2, $Param3 )

        #region Outer script addition
            Start-Transcript -path "C:\Users\Public\TMP\Transcript.txt" -force
            $Global:PSScriptName =  "Scriptblock"
            $PSCommandPath = "C:\Users\Public\TMP\Scriptblock"
        #endregion

        get-date
        $User = whoami
        $Runas = Test-ElevatedRights
        write-host "User = $User"
        write-host "Runas = $Runas"
        write-host "Param1 = $Param1"
        write-host "Param2 = $Param2"
        write-host "Param3 = $Param3"

        #region Outer script addition (return replace)
            $User | Export-CliXML -Path "C:\Users\Public\TMP\Result.xml" -Force
            try{ stop-transcript }catch{}
            exit
        #endregion
}

Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock $ScriptBlock -ArgumentList  $Arguments
```

And arguments.

```
test-test-test
7 июля 2022 г. 1:08:56
True
```

Then we want to add credential to start under different account.

```
$EncodedCommand = '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'

$Arguments =   '-Noexit', '-NoLogo', '–NoProfile', '-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned', "-EncodedCommand $EncodedCommand"

$Credential = get-credential 'HOME-PC\Alex'
$DomainAndUserName = $Credential.UserName.Split("\")

$ProcessStartInfoParam = [ordered]@{
    Arguments       = $Arguments -join ' '
    CreateNoWindow  = $False
    FileName        = 'powershell'
    WindowStyle     = 'Normal'
    LoadUserProfile = $False
    UseShellExecute = $False
    Domain          = $DomainAndUserName | Select-Object -first 1
    UserName        = $DomainAndUserName | Select-Object -last 1
    Password        = $Credential.Password   
}

$ProcessStartInfo = New-Object -TypeName 'System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo' -Property $ProcessStartInfoParam
$Process = New-Object 'System.Diagnostics.Process'

$Process.StartInfo = $ProcessStartInfo
$Process.Start()
```

We have error `Exception calling "Start" with "0" argument(s): "The parameter is incorrect."` 
My main idea is to make powershell function that will run scriptblock and powershell files with different credentials and with option of runas.
Whats wrong with the new script?

Comment: Your code worked fine for me.  I _did_ swap your encoded command for an encoded version of `Get-Process`.  Maybe the issue is related to your actual command you're running - it looked ok, but I didn't run it :-).  It could be that now that the command is running as someone else, there are rights/permissions issues - try a simpler command like I did to see if that's where the issue lies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happend because of strange behavour while proccessing powershell encoded commands.
See my question [System.Diagnostics.Process run Powershell encoded command strange behaviour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72910186/system-diagnostics-process-run-powershell-encoded-command-strange-behaviour).