# System.Diagnostics.Process run Powershell encoded command strange behaviour

Tags: powershell, comments

I want to run encoded powershell command through System.Diagnostics.Process

```
#Region successfull test
    $Command = {
        #$Error.clear()
        #[Console]::OutputEncoding = [System.Text.Encoding]::GetEncoding( "utf-8" )
        write-host 'test'

        #Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock $ScriptBlock -ArgumentList  $Arguments
    }
    $Bytes          = [System.Text.Encoding]::Unicode.GetBytes( $Command.ToString() )
    $EncodedCommand = [Convert]::ToBase64String( $Bytes )
#endregion
$Arguments =   '-Noexit', '-NoLogo', '–NoProfile', '-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned', "-EncodedCommand $EncodedCommand"
$Credential = Get-Credential
$DomainAndUserName = $Credential.UserName.Split("\")

$ProcessStartInfoParam = [ordered]@{
    Arguments       = $Arguments -join ' '
    CreateNoWindow  = $False
    FileName        = 'powershell'
    WindowStyle     = 'Normal'
    LoadUserProfile = $False
    UseShellExecute = $False
    Domain          = $DomainAndUserName | Select-Object -first 1
    UserName        = $DomainAndUserName | Select-Object -last 1
    Password        = $Credential.Password    
}

$ProcessStartInfo = New-Object -TypeName 'System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo' -Property $ProcessStartInfoParam
$Process = New-Object 'System.Diagnostics.Process'

$Process.StartInfo = $ProcessStartInfo
$Process.Start()
```

Script above work fine and we get `test` output. 
When i try to modify this script, just add one COMMENTED line 
`#$Arguments  = [System.Management.Automation.PSSerializer]::Deserialize( [System.Text.Encoding]::Unicode.GetString([System.Convert]::FromBase64String( $EncodedArguments )) )`
in the command scriptblock, for example after `write-host 'test'`.
 I have failed script with error `Exception calling "Start" with "0" argument(s): "The parameter is incorrect."`
What happend? Commented line mean nothing.

P.S. Without credential this script work fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run powershell commands is about quoting! just change `$arguments` to
`` $Arguments =   '-Noexit', '-NoLogo', '–NoProfile', '-ExecutionPolicy `"RemoteSigned`"', "-EncodedCommand `"$EncodedCommand`"" ``, add quotation on RemoteSigned and $EncodedCommand. Now its work fine.